# Is it possible to iterate list with for loop only?

Tags: c#, list, algorithm

Here is the class in C# in console program

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name;
        public int BirthYear;
        public int Age(int birthYear)
        {
            DateTime presents = DateTime.Now;
            int presentAge = presents.Year - birthYear;
            return presentAge;
        }

    }
```

and also the main program

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input peoples: ");
            int people = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Person a = new Person();
            for(int i = 0; i < people; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Person {0}", i + 1);
                Console.Write("Enter the name: ");
                a.Name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter the birth year: ");
                a.BirthYear = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                int present = a.Age(a.BirthYear);
                Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}, your age is {1} years old", a.Name, present);
            }
        }
```

I inputted 2 people and the results are like this:

```
Person 1
Enter the name: Lu Bu
Enter the birth year: 1998
Hello Lu Bu, your age is 23 years old
Person 2
Enter the name: Diao Chan
Enter the birth year: 2000
Hello Diao Chan, your age is 21 years old
```

I wanna achieve the result like this:

```
Person 1
Enter the name: Lu Bu
Enter the birth year: 1998
Person 2
Enter the name: Diao Chan
Enter the birth year: 2000
Hello Lu Bu, your age is 23 years old
Hello Diao Chan, your age is 21 years old
```

Is it possible to achieve with `for` loop only or is it must with `List<>`?

PS: The list in the question i mean **isn't** `List<>` though

Comment: So you want to have one loop to have all your user input, then _after_ it's done, you want to print all the data you've submitted? Well you're going to need a way to carry the data over from those two loops.

Comment: You could append the Hello message to a StringBuilder from within the loop and write it to Console after the loop exits. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I can't see how you would do that without two loops, and a collection of some sort.

Comment: You have an undetermined count of people, so you need a collection to store them, then a loop to write your sentence for each. ANyway, in your example, each person overwrite the previous since there is only one instance of Person. I doubt it is want you want ?

Comment: @Crowcoder can you show me how to do it?

Comment: @PostJavanese someone beat me to it, though I wouldn't use both .AppendLine() and .Append(), I'd just use .AppendLine("...the message...")

Comment: Why are you using the same object for every person? You create a new instance of `Person` => `a`, but are recycling that `Person` object: `a`. You need to create a new `Person` object for each person, store these into a collection and then do what you need with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the information provided (`hellos`) and print it in the end. You don't have to use `List<string>`, it can be any collection (say, `Queue<string>`) or even a `StringBuilder`:

```
        StringBuilder hellos = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i < people; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Person {0}", i + 1);
            Console.Write("Enter the name: ");
            a.Name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter the birth year: ");
            a.BirthYear = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int present = a.Age(a.BirthYear);

            // Instead of printing, we collect the data...
            if (hellos.Length > 0)
              hellos.AppendLine();

            hellos.Append($"Hello {a.Name}, your age is {present} years old");
        }

        // ...and after the loop we print out all the data collected 
        Console.WriteLine(hellos);
```